# Error when using NumPyArrayToFeatureClass in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, numpy

I am trying to write out a structured numpy array to a feature class using ArcPy, but this error message is returned:

> File "`<ipython-input-104-556b13ea80bd>`", line 1, in 
> arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(a,'b',['SHAPE@XY'],spatRef)

Even reading a feature class into a numpy array and then try to export as a feature class generates the same error. For example, if I have a feature class ("fc") that I import into a numpy array in python, I can't export it back as a feature class.

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.da as da

a = da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("fc", ["SHAPE@XY"]) ## get feature class as structured numpy array
spatRef = arcpy.Describe("fc").spatialReference
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(a,'b',['SHAPE@XY'],spatRef)
```

generates the same error message. Any hints on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Is there any more to your error message? That looks like just the beginning of the error message, not the end part that would say which line of code is having problems or what the type of error is. For example of a full error message take a look at https://anenadic.github.io/2014-11-10-manchester/novice/python/07-errors.html.

Comment: No, I have copied the entire message. You can try it if you have ArcGIS. Just replace "fc" with some spatial point file that you have.

Comment: When I ran the code that you presented, preceded by setting `fc` to a point feature class of my choice, I got the expected error of `NameError: name 'da' is not defined`.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x (with ArcMap) or 3.x (with ArcGIS Pro)?

Comment: What are you using as your IDE?  If it's other than IDLE, have you tried running the same code from IDLE as a test?

Comment: I edited the code in the question so that `da` is available. I have tried this in both Python 2.7 (ArcGIS 10.7) and 3.5 (ArcGIS Pro 2.5). I have used SPYDER as my IDE, as well as running the code from the python GUI within ArcGIS. In addition, I have tried it at the CMD command prompt in Windows 10. All approaches return the same error.